# ANTLR conditional Lexer

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar, lexer

I have the following ANTLR grammar

```
relation
  : IDENTIFIER EQUAL relative_date
; 
relative_date
 : K_NOW (PLUS | MINUS) NUMERIC_LITERAL TIME_UNIT
;

IDENTIFIER 
 : //'"' (~'"' | '""')* '"'
 '`' (~'`' | '``')* '`'
 | '[' ~']'* ']'
 | [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_.0-9]* 
;

TIME_UNIT
 : ('h'|'m'|'s'|'d'|'w'|'M'|'y'|'q')
;

PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
EQUAL: '=';
K_NOW : N O W;
NUMERIC_LITERAL
 : [0-9]+ ;
```

If I put `TIME_UNIT` before `IDENTIFIER` parser

- `something = now - 5d`       works
- `d = now - 5d`    DOES NOT work and fails at first `d` and says `IDENTIFIER` required

If I put `TIME_UNIT` after `IDENTIFIER` parser

- `something = now - 5d`    fails at the second `d` and says TIME_UNIT required
- `d = now - 5d`    fails at the second `d` and says TIME_UNIT required

Can someone help me how can I change the grammar to work in both cases? Like when it is a relative date use `TIME_UNIT` lexer otherwise `IDENTIFIER` lexer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer tries to match as much characters as possible. When 2 or more lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first "wins".

So, the input `d` matches both `TIME_UNIT` and `IDENTIFIER`, but because `IDENTIFIER` is defined first, it wins. In other words: the rule `TIME_UNIT` will never be matched.

The solution, put `TIME_UNIT` before `IDENTIFIER`:

```
TIME_UNIT
 : ('h'|'m'|'s'|'d'|'w'|'M'|'y'|'q')
 ;

K_NOW
 : N O W
 ;

IDENTIFIER 
 : //'"' (~'"' | '""')* '"'
   '`' (~'`' | '``')* '`'
 | '[' ~']'* ']'
 | [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_.0-9]* 
 ;
```

(Note that `K_NOW` will also need to be placed before `IDENTIFIER`!)

However, now the input `d`, `h`, `m`, etc. will never become an `IDENTIFIER` because these will now always become a `TIME_UNIT`. You cannot change this, that is how ANTLR's lexer works. You can handle this in the parser like this:

```
identifier
 : IDENTIFIER
 | TIME_UNIT
 ;

TIME_UNIT
 : ('h'|'m'|'s'|'d'|'w'|'M'|'y'|'q')
 ;

IDENTIFIER 
 : //'"' (~'"' | '""')* '"'
   '`' (~'`' | '``')* '`'
 | '[' ~']'* ']'
 | [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_.0-9]* 
 ;
```

and then use the rule `identifier` in your parser rules instead of `IDENTIFIER`:

```
relation
 : identifier EQUAL relative_date
 ;
```

Comment: @Richa I made a small edit regarding the `K_NOW` token.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to implement that within my code

Answer (score -1):

You could change `NUMERIC_LITERAL TIME_UNIT` into one lexer rule `DURATION` and parse the duration yourself

```
relative_date
 : K_NOW (PLUS | MINUS) DURATION
;

DURATION
 : [0-9]+ SPACE* ('h'|'m'|'s'|'d'|'w'|'M'|'y'|'q')
;

SPACE
 : [ \u000B\t\r\n]
;
```

Comment: This will cause `123456789 hi` to be tokenised as `123456789 h` (DURATION) and `i` (IDENTIFIER). Most likely not what Richa is after...

Comment: @BartKiers actually no , it kind of works for me. I get an error node at `i` which looks ok.  Is there something I am missing

Comment: @Richa you probably haven't regenerated the lexer and parser. It will do as I just explained. Check this code: https://gist.github.com/bkiers/248f80ad1d40948b5ea296245c7bc2d8 Or else there are more rules which you haven't shown that are conflicting. Anyway, I wouldn't go with the suggestion described here.

Comment: Yes @BartKiers you are correct. I did not paste the whole grammar file here, just the part  I was struggling with, to avoid noise in the question.